# Swift Firestore Get Document ID

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using FirebaseFirestore for my database.

I have an array of Lists with a name and description.  I'd also like to grab each lists unique documentId.  Is this possible?

List.swift

```
struct List {
    var name:String
    var description:String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "name":name,
            "description":description
        ]
    }
}
```

ListTableViewController.swift

```
func getLists() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        db.collection("lists").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting documents: \(error)")
            } else {
                self.listArray = querySnapshot!.documents.flatMap({List(dictionary: $0.data())})
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found you can get the documentId by doing...

```
    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
        print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
    }
```

But how do I store this in my List to be able to call later?

Answer (score 9):

1.Suppose you are getting documents in snapshot.

```
    guard let documents = ducomentSnapshot?.documents else {
      print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
      return
   }
```

// Get documentId of each document objects using this code.

```
  for i in 0 ..< documents.count {
        let dictData = documents[i].data()
        let documentID = documents[i].documentID
        print("Document ID \(documentID)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if this is the best way but I appended to the listArray and it seems to work.

```
self.listArray.append(List(name: document["name"] as! String, description: document["description"] as! String, documentId: document.documentID))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an id attribute to your list struct:

```
struct List {
    var name:String
    var description:String
    var id: String?

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "name":name,
            "description":description
        ]
    }
}
```

Then when mapping your documents manually assign the id attribute:

```
list = documents.compactMap{ (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> List? in
    var listItem = try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: List.self)
    listItem?.id = queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID
    return listItem
}
```