# get all collection field at once firestore

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hi im using firestore in my application and everything works fine , i can get the document but what i want is to get the field in this document . in the application it gives me the documentID like this [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmuf4.png) and i want to display the field in this document like this [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Zty.png)

i tried this code but it doesn't work with me

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase

class orderTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet var order: UITableView!


var firstName = [String]()

   var db: Firestore!
 
override func viewDidLoad() {

    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    order.dataSource = self
    order.delegate = self
    
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    
  
    loadData()
  
}



func loadData() {
   
   
    db.collection("order").whereField(“firstname”, isEqualTo: true).getDocuments()  {(querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                        self.firstName.append(document.get("firstname") as? String ?? "")
                      
                    }
                }
                print(self.firstName)

                self.order.reloadData()
            }

        
        }
    



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    240
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


return firstName.count
    
         }
    





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "order", for: indexPath) as! orderTableViewCell
    
   
    let firstname = firstName[indexPath.row]
  
           print("Array is populated \(firstName)")
     
           return cell
 
}

}
```

Comment: It's not working because the field in your database is not *firstname* used here `.whereField(“firstname”` and here `.get("firstname")`. It's `first name` according to the screenshot. But your syntax is correct `let fName = doc.get("first name") as? String ?? "No First Name"`. The rest of the question is unclear because the query is for all first name that are true and your screenshot is showing the first name field is a string. You're also getting ALL documents that match that query so you are getting it for all of those users. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay what i want is i want to get the first name value

Comment: @Jay actually i want to get the sub collection from each document

Comment: @Jay please help me with this , im trying to accomplish it since 1 month and i asked this question 3 times in stackOverFlow but no one respond

Comment: For anyone to really help, your question needs clarity 1) Your documents don't have sub collections as shown in the question. 2) There are errrors in the code in the question 3) the code in the question doesn't match the linked screenshot. All of that makes the question very unclear. Also, links can break and if that happens, the question become useless to future readers since they can't see your Firestore structure. Include the screenshots or structures in the action question and remove the links.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the DocumentID to get the field values:

```
func loadData() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collection("users").document(documentID)
    ref.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let dataDescription = document.data()!["first name"]
            self.firstName.append(dataDescription as! String)
        }
    }
}
```

This does mean you need to know what the documentID is. When creating the document, you should set it to something like a unique userID and save it somewhere during the user session to access it.

Comment: yeah i did it and it works with me , but it is possible to get the field for each documentID ?

Comment: @Faisal ```let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"``` this will return the full JSON as a string ex: "["first name": "val"]". You can get the field from this string.

Comment: thanks alot it works with me but it is possible to do it without using specific document Id or it is impossible ?

Comment: This might work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743458/swift-firestore-get-document-id